# Need help with C# Server/Client style program

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, client

I've always wanted to learn TCP or UDP(I hear UDP sucks though) in C# but I can never find ANY tutorial that can teach it. I mean, I've googled tutorials to the point where the results aren't even relevant anymore. Almost every tutorial I've come across explains TCP as if I already knew it, or they introduce terms but never explain them. After a few months, I have made absolutely NO progress. Any help here?

Note: I am not a beginner programmer, I have experience making programs. It's just the TCP tutorials out there suck.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of an application you'd like to write? Also, any tutorial that makes lame arguments such as "UDP sucks" is obviously written by somebody who doesn't understand networking. Better not read those.

Comment: UDP doesn't suck, it's just used for different purposes.  They both have their place.

Comment: An example of an application I'd like to write? Well, nothing specific comes to mind. I suppose just a simple, send data to the server and then send the data back to all clients. Just something to help me get the hang of this.

Comment: So in other words, you'd like to write a chat application. Adding that to your question (or even googling for that) might help.

Comment: I'm just looking to learn some form of server/client program. I guess I chat program will cover both sending data to the server, and sending data to the client. I can try and google it, I'm not sure if the future tutorials will be any better than the previous ones.

Answer (score 3):

You're possibly searching with the wrong keywords. The keyword is *sockets*. The TCP/IP programming API is called sockets, on pretty much all platforms including .NET.

Answer (score 0):

try [codeproject.com](http://codeproject.com)

They have a lot of tutorials with pretty good code samples about TCP/UDP communication (among other things).

[One of the many](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/TCPIPChat.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's difficult to find tutorials for TCP and UDP specifically because they are specific protocols (although very frequently used) and Microsoft are trying to abstract all these concepts so that your application is not dependent of the underlying technology.

Nowadays, you'll be advised to use Windows Communication Foundation (WCF); and you have a lot of resources from MSDN or the [beginner's guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784).

By the way, *learning* TCP cannot be done with a tutorial, but with a book focused on networking such as [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136079679). If you do so, you'll also learn why UDP doesn't "suck"...

Answer (score 0):

The reason there is no C# tutorial is because it is not needed. You basically ask "is there a course telling me how the rules are on streets when I drive a Mercedes". Hint: there are the rules how to drive n streets, and there is a manual for a Mercedes car.

Or: there are books about the IP protocol, and then there is the .NET documentation how .NET implements this. If you ever want to be more than a junior in the field of programming then better get used to learn abstract concepts separate and do not expect a full "howto" for every simple step.

Now, TCP / UDP are fully separate items. They both extend TCP and they have very different uses. Saying "udp sucks" would be quite ignorant towards a lot of programs I know that would never work with TCP and require the fast and easy data distribution of UDP (which, contrary to TCP, also supports multicast). Most of my traffic counting in gb) external these days is UDP based because udp does not get stuck on a lost packet, and list packets can be easily requeried with a specialized higher level (application level) protocol. TCP has the really nasty habit of getting stuck up to 3 minutes when a packet is lost. Sometimes (like: financial data, voip) this is not really acceptable. Most programs love the easy handling of TCP, but it comes with a significant price.

Answer (score 0):

UDP is a different beast.

however, I found this very useful as a starting point: [TCP/IP tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-simple-threaded-tcp-server)

Comment: Hah oops, posted the same link :P

Answer (score 0):

I've written some .NET-based TCP/IP posts [on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html).

They're not a tutorial; rather, they are a few articles on common mistakes. I'd recommend reading them after you understand the tutorials. I also list a couple of good TCP/IP books under the [resources section](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2009/05/tcpip-resources.html).